# How to check the asses image exist or not React Native

Tags: typescript, react-native

I want to set the local assest image if its exist or wants to use the server image.

```
    const getSource = (product: Product) => {
    try {
      const src = require(`../../assets/images/comman/${product.image}`)
      return src
    } catch (err) {
      //Do whatever you want when the image failed to load here
      return `${DEFAULT_API_CONFIG.url}/view/${product.image}`
    }
  }
```

**But it gives me error invalid call**

Answer (score 0):

require() is used by NodeJs to require files (mostly modules) at build-time. It can not be used to dynamically get files at runtime.

Instead you need to interact with your devices file system. There are several libraries to do so like expo-filesystem or react-native-fs